# Has the BitForce Bitcoin Miner be connected to a PC all the time?

Tags: asic, mining-setup

When the [BitForce Bitcoin Miner](https://products.butterflylabs.com/homepage/5-gh-s-bitcoin-miner.html) is mining, does it have to be connected to a PC all the time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Mining devices such as this are merely highly-specialized processors that communicate with a computer via serial over USB. The computer is necessary in order to tell the device what to do, and to get its result to post to the mining system (i.e. a pool or `bitcoind`).

Comment: Really? This means, additional to the energy consumptions of the Miner comes the energy consumed by the PC/Laptop?

Comment: Yes. There's a bit of an assumption that you'd already have it running 24/7, or that you're running a lower power machine anyway. The hashrate to wattage ratio of an ASIC will always beat that of a GPU.

Comment: @powtac Keep in mind that you can have very low power footprint devices connected. ie, android tablet, or phones or Raspberry pi device. There is a article made by a guy from NZ showing his setup using the 5GH/s butterfly lab device running with raspberry pi which was using a total of 44wat IIRC